# Как задать высоту Entry поля в ttk?

Tags: python, tkinter

Как задать высоту поля Entry в from tkinter import ttk?

```
r = ThemedTk(theme='adapta')

e = ttk.Entry(r, height=180)
e.grid(column=1, row=1)

r.mainloop()
```

> _tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-height"

Или же как сделать определенное количество строк в высоту.

Comment: У ttk через стили только.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Такого свойства нет. Но зато у Tkinter есть многострочное поле для ввода - Text.В нем можно задать высоту параметром height.Но если вам нужно только Entry, то тогда вы можете изменить шрифт(font) тогда entry само станет выше.Также вы можете изменить высоту виджета в place(не пробовал с grid). Пример:

```
from tkinter import Entry, Tk

window = Tk()
t = Entry(window)
t.place(width=150,height=50)

window.mainloop()
```

И еще один вариант с использованием ipady.Пример:

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()

a = Label(root,text="input")
a.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5,pady=5)

entry = Entry(root,width=30)
entry.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=5,pady=10,ipady=3)

root.geometry("600x300+150+150")

root.mainloop()
```

Подробнее можно узнать [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24501606/tkinter-python-entry-height)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126380/discussion-on-answer-by-smart-beetle----entry---ttk).